# JMeter - Samplers fail when running distributed in stripped batch mode

Tags: jmeter

In my test I run a script sampler(BSF Sampler) that uses the result of the HTTP Request Sampler before it.
The problem is that when I run the test, distributed, in mode=StrippedBatch (the default mode) the script sampler fails.

Here's a striped down wersion of my script: (the result is 0)

```
bytes = prev.getResponseData();
OUT.println(bytes.length);
```

I have tryed the test localy and also distributed in mode=Standard and it works fine (the problem is not present).

Does this mean that slave can't access the result of the samplers, if the data is not send to the master? Isn't that a big hit on the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StrippedBatch mode does this:

> result.setBytes(result.getBytes());
>
> result.setResponseData(new byte[0]);

Which is why you get your "strange" results.

Your option would be to do it in Post Processor and save your var in Thread Variables.

But it is not a good thing to save the full response as it can consume a lot of memory.